# How do I make Reactjs access deeply nested data from a json response? I'm getting a TypeError when I try to access them

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json

I am currently learning react and I'm trying to use real-world APIs' as a data source for my react app. I am using an API which provides a json response as follows.
[json response from the API](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V8rWk.png)
When I try to console.log the info, I am able to print it out, but using it in the app is giving me this error
[error message while trying to fetch data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CUlr8.png).
for example, I am trying to fetch *JSON.data.cards[0].groupedCard.cardGroupMap.RESTAURANT.cards[0].card.card.info.id* But the app is complaining that it's not defined.

While I was going through other responses, I did figure out to have an await for the promise to resolve and then set it to the variable.

const data = await fetch("LINK_TO_API");
const json = await data.json();

I am able to access the data through console.log, but not able to use it within my application.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using the useEffect hook to fetch data, and if you want to access the data child components from the highest order commponent, you can use the useContext hook to manage the state of data.
**Here is how you can use the useEffect:**

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

const YourComponent = () => {

        const [data, setData] = useState(null);
        const [error, setError] = useState(null);
    
        useEffect(() => {
        const fetchData = async () => {
          try {
            const response = await fetch("LINK_TO_API");
            if (!response.ok) {
              throw new Error('Network response was not ok');
            }
            const json = await response.json();
            setData(json.data);
          } catch (error) {
            setError(error);
          }
         };
    
         fetchData();
         }, []); // Empty dependency array means this effect will run once when the component mounts
    
        if (error) {
            return <div>Error: {error.message}</div>;
        }
    
        if (!data) {
            return <div>Loading...</div>;
        }
    
        // Now you can safely access your data
        const yourValue = 
     
     data.cards[0].groupedCard.cardGroupMap.RESTAURANT.cards[0].card.card.info.id;
    
      return (
        <div>
          {/* Render your component using the data */}
          <p>{yourValue}</p>
        </div>
      );
    };

export default YourComponent;
```

If json returns an array, it is better to use map method to access data instead of `const yourValue = data.cards[0].groupedCard.cardGroupMap.RESTAURANT.cards[0].card.card.info.id;`

Comment: Thank you very much! I was using the useEffect hook, the 2 lines of code for the API were inside the hook. I feel I did not implement the setdata function correctly. I will try it out soon!